# how to move teeth with jaw mesh?

Tags: mesh

How do I move or rotate the selected teeth when I also want to rotate or move the jaw mesh, without the teeth moving outside the jaw? I tried to rotate the selected teeth and the jaw mesh together, but the teeth goes outside the jaw mesh and I have to manualy move the teeth after I moved or rotated the jaw mesh on the model.

Comment: Have you tried adding an armature? Another option would be to make vertice groups of the jaw and the teeth.

Answer (score 2):

Select the teeth (<kbd>RClick</kbd>), select the jaw (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RClick</kbd>), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent them, select "object" in the menu. now if you move/rotate/scale the jaw, the teeth will follow